# Как определить выбор memoji в системной клавиатуре? (iOS)

Tags: ios

Хочу определить выбор memoji в системной клавиатуре, чтобы выполнять определенные дальнейшие действия. Может, кто-то знает?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, никак не отследить, равно как и не переключить например раскладку программно